# I don't know how to make my Jtable scrollable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I made a Jtable in my class, but once it fills up the whole designing page, it can't display the content further down. I decided to make the table scrollable.  Below are my codes to initialize the Jtable:

```
brandTbl.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
        },
        new String[] {
            "Name", "Status", "ID"
        }
    ));
    brandTbl.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    brandTbl.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
    brandTbl.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
    brandTbl.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    brandTbl.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    brandTbl.setBounds(490, 125, 480, 271);
    contentPane.add(brandTbl);
```

I tried to use JScrollPane, but my IDE told me it can't be resolved to a type.

Comment: Don't do this: `brandTbl.setBounds(490, 125, 480, 271)'`. Period.

Comment: you must put the table in a `JScrollPane` (as its `ViewportView`) - see its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html), it sure is a valid type (if correctly `import`ed) -- also check Oracle's tutorial [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#show)

Comment: Yes, put the JTable into a JScrollPane, and then place the scroll pane into a container that uses BorderLayout, such as the ContentPane, if you wish. Never constrain the table's size in such an artificial way either as that will mess up the scroll pane's functioning.

Comment: If I delete `brandTbl.setBounds()`, then the entire table would disappear. @HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: Because you're likely using a null layout -- DON'T

Comment: Read the Swing docs to learn how to use JTables, JScrollPanes and layout managers. Otherwise you're code will be fighting against the Swing library, which is not wise, fun or useful.